# Open Space with Hot Roof, best ventilation?

Tags: insulation, ventilation

I just purchased a home in Minnesota, the house came with a detached garage with a living space above that we want to make livable. The lower-level is partially buried below grade. The picture attached shows its current state, with no sheetrock on the walls, just the  closed-cell sprayfoam. The Mini-split heating-cooling system is installed along with two exhaust fans - one on each gabble end.

My question is about fresh air ventilation. Should a passive intake be placed somewhere? Should we install a Heat Recovery Ventilation System? Any ideas would be helpful.

[image: house cross section]

Comment: Well, it  sounds like you already have ventilation fans, but those would be very energy inefficient, exhausting conditioned air and take in unconditioned air. HRV is a good idea and may be required in your area.  I'm posting this as a comment because I'm including a product idea.  My son just built a very energy efficient house and for HRV he used Lunos modules:  https://foursevenfive.com/lunos-e/  They are pricey and there may be better options. I installed them and they are high quality.  The instructions are a little wonky bc I think they are German manufactured.